# Python BigQuery - How to append to a table if the rows are new and ignore rows that are duplicates

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using a scheduler that triggers the query every 5 mins and appended to the destination table which has worked the first time but shortly after I received an error saying: `google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table.`

```
 SELECT
    job_id,
    creation_time,
    query,
    total_bytes_processed
    FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
    WHERE project_id ='project-name'
    AND creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible to for each time this query is ran to only append new rows and if there are duplicates from a previous query to ignore those rows.

Update :
I found the merge statement  which will enable the query to add new rows if they do not match if my logic is correct.

```
MERGE project-id.dataset.table as Target
USING 
(
    SELECT
    job_id,
    creation_time,
    query,
    total_bytes_processed
    FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
    WHERE project_id ='project-id-name'
    AND creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC
    LIMIT 100
)  Query
ON Target = Query
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ROW)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is indeed caused by too many data and metadata updates per table per day, so narrowing down this number of updates should solve your issue.

You have information about merge statement in [1] and some merge examples in [2]. 
Regarding your query, the merge statement seems to be correctly written but doesn't give the result you want. Does it works?

Maybe you can try changing the "ON Target = Query" statement to "ON Target.job_id = Query.job_id", in my understanding you are appending information about queries so the job id is what you are comparing, not the whole table.

Also, if you say the query is getting triggered every 5 minutes, you could lower the window of queries you are selecting on the source: "AND creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)" to a window lower than a 1 day interval.

I'm suggesting options as I don't really know your data. I hope it helps and don't hesitate to ask more.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples